# Installing Devise - ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Being a RoR beginner since a week, I've been trying to install the Devise gem via [Railscast Episode 209](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) and alternatively via the [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). However, after several hours of trial and error I can't seem to overcome the following error:

*/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:39:in `check_options_validity': **The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk.** Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option? (ArgumentError)*

This comes up right after:

```
rake db:migrate
```

The *routes.db* file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'users/new'

  root  'static_pages#home'
  get 'home'        => 'static_pages#home'
  get 'over'        => 'static_pages#over'
  get 'contact'     => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'      => 'users#new'
end
```

And *user.rb*:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

After commenting *devise_for :users* the error disappears.

I've tried:

- going through all StackOverflow and GitHub threads containing this ArgumentError, but they don't resemble my situation
- creating a table Users before the commando *rails generate devise User* as suggested somewhere, but that doesn't do the trick either.
- search for RegExp tests, but I can't find them in my code.

Can anyone get me going again? How do I know where the error comes from based on the output?

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? You can check it by typing rails -v

Comment: That's rails 4.2.2

Comment: Attr_accessible has deprecated in rails 4, replacing by strong parameters in controller instead. You have to remove the line `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation` in your model file.

Comment: I took it out but still got the same error. Then put it back in and added gem 'protected_attributes' as an alternative, but rake db:migrate still gives the same error... :(